# Is it possible to use an 'if' statement when installing packages in salt

Tags: python, salt-stack

I have a `packages.sls` file with a list of packages to install during deployment.

Is it possible to add an `if` statement, and depending on the minion's name, decide whether the package will be installed or not?

Here is an example:

```
zabbix-agent-removed:
  pkg.purged:
    - name: zabbix-agent
    - zabbix-agent: '<4.0.0'
    - ignore_epoch: True

# add if not minion == XX, install the following one:
zabbix-agent-installed:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: zabbix-agent
    - zabbix-agent: '>=4.0.0'
    - ignore_epoch: True
    - require:
      - pkgrepo: zabbix-agent-repo-added
# end if here    

scikit-learn:
  pip.installed:
    - name: scikit-learn == 0.19.1
    - require:
      - pkg: python-pip
```

Answer (score 2):

according to the doc yes: [here](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/states_pt3.html) they offer you an example about how to do it:

```
apache:
  pkg.installed:
    {% if grains['os'] == 'RedHat' %}
    - name: httpd
    {% elif grains['os'] == 'Ubuntu' %}
    - name: apache2
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw that page while researching, but do you know if it is possible to add the 'if' statement to include all of this block? so I will not install anything if some variable is equal to a certain input?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to separate the 'processing' (install packages) and the 'data' (packages to be installed).
In salt the first are **states** and the second are **pillar**.

You install packages state could be as simple as:

```
install_packages:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs: {{ salt['pillar.get']('packages', []) }}
```

and then you just set pillar to be different depending of `grains['os']`. Pillars have a targetting system of `top.sls` similar to states.
You can find documentation on pillars here https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/pillar.html or here https://docs.saltstack.com/en/getstarted/config/pillar.html, and about targetting https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/.

*You can also decide to use a saltstack formula maintained by the community which already provides this functionality https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/packages-formula*

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `minion-var` in your `grains` file besides your other non-standard grains in Salt Minion:

```
minion_var: minion1
```

And your state (.sls) file at Salt Master can be amended as below to consider you requirement.

```
zabbix-agent-removed:
  pkg.purged:
    - name: zabbix-agent
    - zabbix-agent: '<4.0.0'
    - ignore_epoch: True

{% if grains['minion_var'] | default ('NA') == 'minion1' %}
zabbix-agent-installed:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: zabbix-agent
    - zabbix-agent: '>=4.0.0'
    - ignore_epoch: True
    - require:
      - pkgrepo: zabbix-agent-repo-added
{% endif %}    

scikit-learn:
  pip.installed:
    - name: scikit-learn == 0.19.1
    - require:
      - pkg: python-pip
```

Here we are checking if we receive our expected grain from the minion. If yes , then it would perform `zabbix-agent-installed` state. And if it fails then default value would tolerate the behaviour for other minions which do not hold the newly introduced grain in it.